# Laravel validation rules based on 2 values

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a form which posts 2 values `property_id` and `email` to an endpoint.

Currently I have form validation which is as follows;

```php
return [
    'email' => ['required', 'email'],
    'property_id' => ['required', 'exists:properties,id'],
];
```

This does alright, but what i want to also do is check the `invites` table to see if the email already exists against that property_id. If it does i want to return a message in the email that says 'An invitation for this email and property already exists'

Is that possible?

Comment: considering `email` as `unique` you can check it with : 
`unique:table_name,column_name`
This will help in checking if the value exists in the  column or not,

Comment: in your case it can be like this for email `'email' => ['required' ,'email','unique:invites,email']`

Comment: Well the email can exist in the invites table multiple times if it with a different property_id, but can only exist once with the same email and property_id

Comment: In that case use it something like this: 

`'email' => ['required', 'email', 'unique:invites,email,property_id,' . $this->property_id],`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can do it using [closure](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#using-closures)

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => [
            'required',
            'email',
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                $propertyId = $this->input('property_id');

                $invitationExists = DB::table('invites')
                    ->where('email', $value)
                    ->where('property_id', $propertyId)
                    ->exists();

                if ($invitationExists) {
                    $fail('An invitation for this email and property already exists.');
                }
            },
        ],
        'property_id' => ['required', 'exists:properties,id'],
    ];
}
```